# getting live webcam feed from opencv to Unity

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I have a project in Unity using openCV 2.3 with Mat images, but Im stuck at finding a way to get a live feed from the webcam to a Unity 2dtexture. I've caught that you somewhat need to pass a array to the plugin dll file, which will then paste the image data into the array, but I don't know how to do that. Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the pointer to the data array from the Mat image and pass it to your other module:

```
VideoCapture cap;
Mat frame;
.....

cap >> frame;
uchar* imgData = (uchar*)(frame.data);
myBeautifulFunctionThatNeedsArray(imgData, frame.cols, frame.rows, ...);
```

Comment: Thx.. it seems like the right thing to do, but due to the deadline of the project I did not get it implemented.